# Why multicast messages with same source ip address get ignored

Tags: linux, network-programming, ip, multicast

I implemented a network discovery process which makes use of multicast messages. It allows to discover specific devices with any ip-address connected to the same segment.

Client A sends a multicast messages, asking for other Clients. The other clients response with a multicast message "I'am here...". Basically this works fine.

But there is one case which causes me troubles.

```
 Client A       Client B
192.168.2.5   192.168.2.5  
    |             |
     \__________ / 
         >>>
  UDP Multicast Message: 
  Source: 192.168.2.5 | Destination: 224.0.0.150
```

The coincident could arise, that Client A which sends the multicast message and Client B both listen to the same ip-address. In this case the source address of the UDP packet is the same as the ip-address of the destination client. Thus the application on Client B does not receive any multicast message.

I guess that the multicast message with the same messages gets blocked and dropped in the ip-stack. Is there a way (socket settings) to receive it anyway.

Comment: Normally is it not possible that two computer have the same ip. I think the switch will not allow to send the package to two diffent ports.

Comment: Of Course two times the same IP is not allowed. But it may happen. Anyway, as I know switches don't care about IP addresses (> Layer 3).

Comment: @Maus Switches don't but the stuff connected to them does, and if they discover 2 machines with the same IP, their ARP cache will get confused and not know where to send the packets, or send to just one of them, or refuse to send almost anything to any of them.

Comment: so, does IP_MULTICAST_LOOP solve ur problem?

Comment: @xijingdai Yes, I marked nos answer as the right answer a long time ago .

Comment: @xijingdai Shouldn't IP_MULTICAST_LOOP just copy my own outgoing packets to all local listening clients? If I wanted to learn information about (possibly misconfigured) same-ip hosts, then I need to receive *their* data, not *mine*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have a host read its own multicast packets(which is often just a filter on the source IP address), this is controlled by the IP_MULTICAST_LOOP socket option.

```
int loop = 1;
setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, &loop, sizeof(loop));
```

Comment: [IP_MULTICAST_LOOP is enabled](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-6.html) by default so you usually won't need to use this setsockopt unless you disable looping in one part of your program and then want to re-enable it.

Comment: This doesn't solve the discovery of same-IP neighbors.